# Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected wordpress

Tags: wordpress, heroku

I've been trying to deploy wordpress onto a heroku app using the tutorial @
http://decielo.com/articles/350/wordpress-on-heroku-up-and-running

Everything works fine and dandy until...

```
18:25:53-~/code/abc_wordpress$ git push production master
Counting objects: 1080, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1058/1058), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1080/1080), 4.48 MiB | 174 KiB/s, done.
Total 1080 (delta 66), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:abc_wordpress.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:abc_wordpress.git'
```

Also, for reference

```
18:25:50-~/code/abc_wordpress$ git remote -v
production  git@heroku.com:abc_wordpress.git (fetch)
production  git@heroku.com:abc_wordpress.git (push)
```

and this too...

```
18:21:48-~/code/abc_wordpress$ heroku config
=== abc_wordpress Config Vars
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL: mysql://...
DATABASE_URL:         mysql://...
```

what's going on?

Comment: Also, you just posted your database credentials on a public forum. You should probably get those rotated before someone does something mean.

Comment: thanks - the database and urls are dummy names and there non-existant - i however appreciate it the tip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing you missed the step where you move the application out of `wordpress/` and into the root of the git respository. Put another way, `git ls-files` should show `index.php`, not `wordpress/index.php`.

The [PHP buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/bin/detect) requires an `index.php` in the root in order to detect your repo as a PHP application.

Comment: i solved the answer by redoing the steps and I believe this may have been a part of it.