# How push Git sub-directory to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, github

On github I have a Rails app in a sub-directory of a directory, `github.com/sadaf2605/directory/subdirectory/{rails app}`. When I try to push this app to Heroku I get an error:

```
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:damp-woodland-7566.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:damp-woodland-7566.git'
```

After reading "[Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695219/heroku-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected-wordpress)", I learned that this sub-directory is causing the problem. But, I want this sub directory to remain at github as it helps me to organize my work yet I don't want to change the route.rb. Is it possible?

Comment: Probably best action would be to make the rails app it's own git repository and then make it a submodule of the first repository.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) plugin.  You can use it to split subtrees from your project into subprojects and back.

`git subtree push --prefix {rails app} heroku master`

Clone the github project and run `sudo sh install.sh` to install the plugin.  Full usage instructions are in the [here](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt)

Comment: Subtree has since been incorporated into `git` so you can now run the command above without the need to install a plugin.