# Heroku Deploy Subdirectory With Access To Sibling Folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have an app(**rails-creator**) that generate's rails apps in a sibling folder(**rails-creator-apps**).

**App structure:**

```
- rails-creator(app to deploy)
- rails-creator-apps(app that rails-creator switches into to generate rails apps)
```

This works on local, but not on Heroku because there is no sibling folder.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185462/how-push-git-sub-directory-to-heroku):

```
git subtree push --prefix rails-creator heroku master
```

but it only pushed **rails-creator**, not **rails-creator-apps**.

I tried what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081699/deploy-a-subdirectory-to-heroku), but it only references rails 2.x and 3.x. When I push to Heroku it fails because Heroku couldn't identify the buildpack.

Is there any way to push both directories to Heroku, but have it reference **rails-creator** for the buildpack?